# Digest Authentication Token Invalid after some time

Tags: c#, iis, windows-phone-8.1, servicestack, digest-authentication

i am just working on my first Windows Phone 8.1 app (Universal if this matters, but only Windows Phone implemented at the moment). And at first all is working very smooth but as soon as my app is running for about 25-30 Minutes I can no longer use my `HttpClient`. I use the `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`.

In my first try`s I used a single`HttpClient`and reused it all the time. As I became aware that this is not working I started using a new`HttpClient` for each request. But still no luck.

This is my method to get a new `HttpClient`:

```
    private HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter
        {
            AllowUI = false,
            CacheControl = { WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache },
            ServerCredential =
                new PasswordCredential(
                BaseApiUri.ToString(),
                credentials.UserName,
                credentials.Password),
        };

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);
        var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
        var httpConnectionOptionHeaderValueCollection = headers.Connection;
        httpConnectionOptionHeaderValueCollection.Clear();
        headers.Accept.TryParseAdd("application/json");
        headers.CacheControl.TryParseAdd("no-cache");
        headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "false");
        headers.Cookie.Clear();

        return httpClient;
    }
```

The extra code setting the headers and clearing cookies are my attempts to stop some kind of caching of connections under the surface that might happen. But still no luck.

My method to make requests my API is like the following:

```
    private async Task<bool> PostNoResponseRequestTo(string relativeUri, object requestContent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var targetUri = new Uri(BaseApiUri, relativeUri);
        var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestContent);
        var content = new HttpStringContent(requestJson, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = this.GetClient())
            {
                var post =
                    await httpClient.PostAsync(targetUri, content).AsTask(cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
                        async request =>
                            {
                                using (var response = await request)
                                {
                                    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                                }
                            },
                        cancellationToken);

                return await post;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This works fine for about 25-30 Minutes after which the calls to the api suddenly start to fail. I start getting a `401` but as you can see i have specified credentials and because those are working and do not change (hardcoded them to test this) i start believing that the problem is on the API side.

This is the response I get:

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 2, Content:      Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent, Headers:
{
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 14:25:06 GMT
    WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+NounceRemoved",charset=utf-8,realm="Digest", Negotiate, NTLM
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}
{
    Content-Length: 1344
    Content-Type: text/html
}
```

My API consists of a Asp.Net project with ServiceStack for its API functionality.
This is running on an IIS with activated digest authentication (all other are disabled).

By inspecting the logs i became aware of a failing API call in front of each successful call. But if i'm right this is by design of digest auth because i have not found a way to tell the client that the other side is using digest auth. I was able to specify this kind of information in my other .Net projects but for some reason Microsoft changed the code (and namespace) for the `HttpClient`. I am also aware of the `HttpClient` in the original namespace that you can get through nuget but this is not working for me as i get an error in my output window as soon as i make any call. This closes my app without any kind of information.

Back to the log i was able to get some information with the help of the extended logging and the tool to analyze them. The error is something like (can't access it right now will edit it later):'Invalid token passed to function/method'.

I really hope that someone can help me to solve this problem as it makes the app nearly unusable. My users have to restart the app every 15 Minutes to be on the save site.

Thanks for all advices that help me.

Comment: Did you manage to resove this issue? I'm have the same problem right now (in UWP). After exactly 10 minutes I only get 401 as response...

Comment: @Dust258 No, sorry we are using a work arround. We just try the authentication multiple times and this works for us.

Answer (score 3):

Try Checking the Machine Key setting in IIS. Automatically generate at runtime if tick will generate a new key every time the app pool is restarted. This might be causing your issue.  The Machine Key can be set on the server, website or application level. As activated digest authentication is encrypted this might be the issue.

[Managing Websites with IIS Manager (part 6) - The Machine Key and Windows Authentication](http://mscerts.programming4.us/programming/managing%20websites%20with%20iis%20manager%20(part%206)%20-%20the%20machine%20key%20and%20windows%20authentication.aspx)

Comment: Had never known about this setting and just tried it. It does not help but i have the feeling that it has increased the time by about 5 Minutes. But it could be just me. Also edited my question with more information.